# Setting up SSHv1 on a server

Tags: ssh, server, openssh

I know SSHv1 is super insecure, however I need to set it up on a server for some testing. Trying to find an older version of openSSH was a hard task in itself, but now trying to set it up is impossible.

I'm trying to use openSSH 2.1.1 and openSSL 1.0.1.

From what I can tell, openSSL installs fine, however I run in to issues with openSSH

My configure (`./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc`) works fine, however I run in to issues when I try to `make`

The error I'm getting is: `authfd.c:354:41: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘RSA {aka struct rsa_st}’ buffer_put_int(&buffer, BN_num_bits(key->n));`

I've tried looking around, and have even started looking in some of the openSSL files, I think everything is coded correctly.

My guess is that these errors have something to do with trying to compile old versions of `ssl` and `ssh` with an up to date version of `gcc`

Has anyone managed to set up a server to use SSHv1, or at least have any ideas on how to solve this dereferencing error?

Comment: Not a `c` problem but instead a system admin/package issue.

Comment: @MDXF - the OP does not have code, they have downloaded a package and cannot get it to install.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I do actually have access to the code, as I downloaded them as TAR files, but I honestly don't know what would be relevant in this case.

Comment: Exactly as I suspected.

Answer (score 1):

From the error you see it looks like you are using OpenSSL 1.1.0, which made `RSA` structures opaque and is therefore it is not compatible. Things to resolve:

- Download older OpenSSL (1.0.2 should do that) and build this one
- Configure with `--with-ssh1` switch to enable SSH1 support

Comment: I've solved me error and can now see the openssl version when I issue `/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl version` However I'm still getting the same `dereferencing pointer to incomplete type` error when I try to `make` openSSH